# How to connect diamond shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm wondering how do I connect the right side of block 3 with block 9?

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains} 

%%%<

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %----permette l' uso dei caratteri accentati

\usepackage[italian]{babel} %-----permette la sillabazione secondo le regole italiane

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}% %%%> \begin{document} % bhjdfjklhdfjklhjdfjklhdfkljdfh \tikzstyle{block1}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=6cm] \tikzstyle{block2}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=3cm] \tikzstyle{decision}  = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=2cm] \tikzstyle{line}      = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block1] (1) {\textbf{\small Presentazione Istanza}};
    \node [decision, below of=1, node distance=3cm]  (3)  {\textbf{\small Verifica documentazione}};
    \node [block2, below  of=3, node distance=3.5cm]  (4)  {irricevibilità con possibilità di integrazione};
    \node [block2, left of=3, node distance=4cm] (2)  {comunicazione responsabile del procedimento};
    \node [decision, below of=4, node distance=4 cm] (5) {integrazione effettuata};
    \node [block2, below of=5, node distance=3cm] (6) {istruttoria};
    \node [decision, below of=6, node distance=3 cm] (7) {soggetto a parere commissione};
    \node [block1, below of=7, node distance=3cm] (8) {esito parere commissione};
    \node [block1, below of=8, node distance=3cm] (9) {\textbf{chiusura procedimento}};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (1) -| (2);
    \path [line] (1) -- (3);
    \path [line] (3) -> (4);
    %\path [line] (right of=3) -| (9);
    %\path [line, name path=4to12] (4) -| ([xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm]6.east) |- (12);
    \path [line] (4) -> (5);
    \path [line] (5) -> (6);
    % Define the path but without drawing.
    %\path [name path=6to14] (6) -| ([xshift=2cm, yshift=0cm]6.east) |-(14);
    \path [line] (6) -> (7);
    \path [line] (7) -- (8);
    \path [line] (8) -- (9);

    % Find the intersection of the two paths.    %\path [name intersections={of=4to12 and 6to14}];
    %\coordinate (S)  at (intersection-1);

    % Define a circle around this intersection for the arc.
    %\path[name path=circle] (S) circle(2mm);

    % Find the intersections of second line and circle.
    % \path [name intersections={of=circle and 6to14}];
    %\coordinate (I1)  at (intersection-1);
    %\coordinate (I2)  at (intersection-2);

    % Draw normal line segments, except for portion within circle.
    %\draw (6) -- (I2);
    %\draw[->] (I1)  -| ([xshift=2cm, yshift=0cm]6.east) |- (14);

    % Draw arc at intersection
    %\draw () arc (180:0:2mm); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,calc} 

%%%<

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %----permette l' uso dei caratteri accentati

\usepackage[italian]{babel} %-----permette la sillabazione secondo le regole italiane

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}% %%%> 
\begin{document} % bhjdfjklhdfjklhjdfjklhdfkljdfh 
\tikzstyle{block1}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=6cm] \tikzstyle{block2}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=3cm] \tikzstyle{decision}  = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=2cm] \tikzstyle{line}      = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block1] (1) {\textbf{\small Presentazione Istanza}};
    \node [decision, below of=1, node distance=3cm]  (3)  {\textbf{\small Verifica documentazione}};
    \node [block2, below  of=3, node distance=3.5cm]  (4)  {irricevibilit\`a con possibilit\`a di integrazione};
    \node [block2, left of=3, node distance=4cm] (2)  {comunicazione responsabile del procedimento};
    \node [decision, below of=4, node distance=4 cm] (5) {integrazione effettuata};
    \node [block2, below of=5, node distance=3cm] (6) {istruttoria};
    \node [decision, below of=6, node distance=3 cm] (7) {soggetto a parere commissione};
    \node [block1, below of=7, node distance=3cm] (8) {esito parere commissione};
    \node [block1, below of=8, node distance=3cm] (9) {\textbf{chiusura procedimento}};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (1) -| (2);
    \path [line] (1) -- (3);
    \path [line] (3) -> (4);
    %\path [line] (right of=3) -| (9);
    %\path [line, name path=4to12] (4) -| ([xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm]6.east) |- (12);
    \path [line] (4) -> (5);
    \path [line] (5) -> (6);
    % Define the path but without drawing.
    %\path [name path=6to14] (6) -| ([xshift=2cm, yshift=0cm]6.east) |-(14);
    \path [line] (6) -> (7);
    \path [line] (7) -- (8);
    \path [line] (8) -- (9);

    % Find the intersection of the two paths.    %\path [name intersections={of=4to12 and 6to14}];
    %\coordinate (S)  at (intersection-1);

    % Define a circle around this intersection for the arc.
    %\path[name path=circle] (S) circle(2mm);

    % Find the intersections of second line and circle.
    % \path [name intersections={of=circle and 6to14}];
    %\coordinate (I1)  at (intersection-1);
    %\coordinate (I2)  at (intersection-2);

    % Draw normal line segments, except for portion within circle.
    %\draw (6) -- (I2);
    %\draw[->] (I1)  -| ([xshift=2cm, yshift=0cm]6.east) |- (14);

    % Draw arc at intersection
    %\draw () arc (180:0:2mm); 
    \path [line] (3.east) -| ($(9.east)+(1em,0)$) -- (9.east);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX Looks like Mr. marmot is faster!

Comment: Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated @PhelypeOleinik. As is `below of=`.

Comment: @cfr I agree. Do you think is necessary to revise the answer? (My part did not make use of any deprecated style.)